# fork exec wait exits with error code

Tags: c, unix

I am writing own shell-like program and I keep getting errors on `exec*` function call.

Here is source code of core `processes.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 128
#define EXIT_STR "exit"

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    const char *prompt = "> ";
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    int bytes_read;
    int status;
    pid_t child_p;

    while(1) {
        printf("%s", prompt);
        fflush(stdout);
        bytes_read = read(0, buffer, BUFSIZE);
        buffer[bytes_read-1] = '\0';

        if(strncmp(EXIT_STR, buffer, bytes_read) == 0)
            exit(0);

        if((child_p = fork()) == 0) {
            printf("[*] %d executing: %s\n", getpid(), buffer);
            execlp(buffer, buffer);
            printf("[*] %d got error on execlp\n", getpid());
            exit(1);
        } else {
            waitpid(child_p, &status, 0);
            printf("[*] child returned: %d\n", status);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also simple `other.c` program for testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    printf("Hello. I am %s with pid: %d\n", argv[0], getpid());
    exit(0);
}
```

I use `llvm` on MacOS High Sierra for compilation:

```
 $  llvm-gcc processes.c -o processes -Wall
 $  ./processes
> other
[*] 6040 executing: other
[*] 6040 got error on execl
[*] child returned: 256
> ls
[*] 6041 executing: ls
[*] 6041 got error on execl
[*] child returned: 256
> exit
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you must terminate the argument list to `execlp()` with a null pointer of type `char *`.

Comment: What’s in `buffer`?  Unless it is a single word command like `ls` or `who`, it won’t work.  Note that a newline would screw things up.  Shells take care of newlines for you. When you write your own shell, you have to take care of them.

Comment: Note also that outputting error messages via `perror()` is usually more informative than is printing return codes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger so `buffer[bytes_read-1] = '\0';` isn't doing what I though ti would do?
@JonathanLeffler I know, I am trying to build it step by step

Comment: Isn't because you did `exit(1);`?

Comment: @smac89 `exec*` functions shouldn't return so this code should be unreachable

Comment: No, @gonczor, that's not at all the same thing.  You *do* need to terminate each argument string with a null terminator, but what I'm talking about is adding `(char *) NULL` as a whole additional argument.

Comment: @gonczor that isn't doing what John described. That is terminating a string. You need to also terminate the *argument list* with an additional null *pointer*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it helped. I'll be happy to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Together, the second argument argument to `execlp()` and any subsequent arguments correspond to the strings provided to the new program's `main()` function in its argument vector.  They must all be pointers to null-terminated C strings, except that the end of the list *must* be marked by a null pointer of type `char *`.  For example:

```
execlp(buffer, buffer, (char *) NULL);
```

This is a documented requirement for the arguments to this function, and your program mail fail if you do not satisfy it.  If you wish, you may rationalize it as providing a means for the system to count the elements of the argument vector, so as to pass that number to the new `main()`.  You may also consider that the argument vector itself is documented to be terminated by a null pointer.